# How to solve batch file that keep deleting my file?

Tags: batch-file

How can I fix my batch file??
When I run the command in Windows 10 1903, it run totally fine. But when I run it in Windows 10 2004, the batch keep deleting file that's in the batch folder.

Here is the script (not full) :

```
ipconfig /flushdns
cd %windir%/temp
powershell ri * -recurse -force >NUL
cd %temp%
powershell ri * -recurse -force >NUL
```

this is the line that keep deleting my file in **Windows 10 2004**
Can someone plz help me, I already try to solve it. But I didn't find a way out

Comment: Have you tried ```powershell ri %windir%/temp/* -recurse -force >NUL```?

Comment: I haven't, I'll try it now then

Comment: WOW, you just save my life. Thank you so much, thank you

Comment: You may want to look at the help file for the `CD` command and look specifically at the `/D` option.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than changing directory, directly pass the path of the directory to the `ri` command.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
powershell ri %windir%/temp/* -recurse -force >NUL
powershell ri %temp%/* -recurse -force >NUL
```

Comment: You should really use Windows path separators, which are backward slashes, not 'nix style forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

The `Temp` directory you're trying to empty is inside the protected `%SystemDrive%\Windows` location. In order for it to be emptied, you must, in the first instance, have permission to do that, and generally for that you should be running your script elevated, i.e. 'Run as administrator'.

Also, I would have thought it would be quicker to do this directly with native `cmd.exe` commands, rather than calling out to an external utility like `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`:

```bsh
@"%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe" /FlushDNS
@PushD "%SystemRoot%\Temp" && (RD /S /Q . 2> NUL & PopD)
@PushD "%Temp%" && (RD /S /Q . 2> NUL & PopD)
```

Comment: I will also mention however, that I do not recommend ever emptying the contents of your system and user `Temp` directories like this. Microsoft already provides a Disk Cleanup tool _(`cleanmgr.exe`)_ for performing such tasks.

Comment: I use this folder, because there is no cost. So I tested it in temp folder

Comment: I'm not sure @TadJadwa, what exactly you mean by the comment above, but if you're saying that it is fine to empty those directories, you are wrong. They are used by many applications, _(incorrectly perhaps, given their `temp` name)_, files are stored and used from there during your session, and for use between sessions too. Have you tried my, _intended quicker_, answer above, to see if it performs the task you require of it?